# Nodes aren't being created properly in a single linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

So I'm trying to create a simple single link list which has 2 functions ...one is the create_list() function which enables the user to create as many nodes as he wants and another function is the display() which will simply show all nodes in the list.However,no matter how many values I enter only one node is present in the list and also the display() doesnt work properly as the output shows in an infinite mode.
I've provided the code below if possible please feel free to make appropriate changes in the code

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;

void create_list()
{
    struct node *curr = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *traverse;
    char choice = 'y';
    int user_input;
    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nSORRY CAN'T ALLOCATE ANY MORE MEMORY :(";
        exit(0);
        
    }
    while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\nENTER THE DATA FOR THE NODE\n";
        cin >> user_input;
        curr->data = user_input;
        curr->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = curr;
        }
        else
        {
            traverse = head;
            while (traverse->next != NULL)
            {
                traverse = traverse->next;
            }
            traverse->next = curr;
            cout << "\n" << traverse->next;
        }
        cout << "\nDO YOU WANT TO ENTER ANY OTHER NODES?\n\n";
        cin >> choice;
    }
}
void display()
{
    struct node *show;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nTHERE ARE NO NODES TO SHOW\n";
    }
    else
    {
        show = head;
        while (show->next != NULL && show != NULL)
        {
            cout << "\n" << show->data;
            show = show->next;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    create_list();
    display();
}
```

Comment: It would be worth trying a C++-style linked list instead of a C-style linked list.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but if possible could you please tell me if there's any logical mistake in the code ?...

Comment: If the program isn't working as you intend, there is a logic mistake. Mind you when code is working as intended, there may still be a logic mistake. You just haven't found it yet.

Comment: You only `malloc` a single node, you need to allocate a new object for each node you create

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions I just started with DS so still kinda beginner

Comment: That said, prefer to use `new` over `malloc` in C++. And that said, prefer to use smart pointers over `new`. And library containers over smart pointers. And, where possible, automatic allocations.

Comment: Watch out here: `while (show->next != NULL && show != NULL)` The test for `show != NULL` comes AFTER you use `show` in `show->next != NULL` and possibly break the program. All you should need here is the test for `show != NULL` If  `next` is `NULL`, you'll catch it on the next loop iteration when it's become `show`.

Comment: If you want to implement the list manually, here is a [Singly Linked List Example](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) that shows how to simplify list operations by using both the address of a node and pointer to node.  See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) (yes that Linus)